# Image doesn't fit the frame woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, image-size, storefront

yesterday I asked a question about my site then eventually (thought) solved it myself. But now problem got bigger. What should I do?

The image about problem:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UESGm.png)

and the site is : [Here](http://auvashop.com/product-category/rings/)

Comment: Please post your code here in a JS Fiddle so we can help isolate the problem.

Comment: I don't have any codes I solved problem through woocommerce settings @NathanielFlick